# Перестановка указателей в двумерном динамическом массиве

Tags: c++

Есть динамический массив

```
int **create_array(size_t m, size_t n) {
    int **arr = new int *[m];
    arr[0] = new int[m * n];
    for (size_t i = 1; i != m; ++i)
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + n;
    return arr;
}
```

Необходимо поменять местами с нулевой строку,содержащую минимальный элемент, т.е.
поменять указатели

В функции обмена происходит выход за границы массива. Не могу понять почему.

```
void swap_min(int **mt, int m, int n) {
    int number_row = 0;
    int min = *(*mt);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (*(*mt + i * n + j) < min) {
                min = *(*mt + i * n + j);
                number_row = i;
            }
        }
    }
    if (number_row == 0)
        return;
    else {
        int *tmp = mt[number_row];
        mt[number_row] = mt[0]; // после этой строчки не происходит ничего
        mt[0] = tmp;  // вот после этой строчки ошибка
    }
}
```

Что я делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 1):

Эээ, подождите. `*(*mt + i * n + j) < min`? Вы имели в виду `mt[i][j]`? Тогда так и пишите.

Тем более, если у вас данные идут подряд только в самом начале, а потом вы двигаете указатели, то этот код и вовсе неверен.

Обращение к `mt[0]` не может быть причиной ошибки, т. к. `mt[0]` — это то же, что `*mt`, а к этому элементу вы уже обращались. Попробуйте просмотреть адреса под отладчиком. Ошибка где-то ещё.

**Обновление**

Я оттрассировал ваш код. Ошибки, ведущей к вылету, в самой указанной вами строке нету. Но обращение к `*mt + i*n + j` **после** перестановки неверно (а оно у вас происходит в двух местах: в `show(ar, M, N)` и в `free_array(ar, M)`), и является undefined behaviour. Программы с undefined behaviour имеют право вести себя как угодно и вылетать в любом месте, особенно если у вас хороший оптимизирующий компилятор. Могу поспорить, если вы закомментируете вызовы `show` и `free_array`, вылета не будет.

Comment: До этой строчки (mt + i * n + j) < min указатели не двигаются. Код вида mt[i][j] применяется для обычных массивов. А это (mt + i * n + j) арифметика указателей. Поэтому извините, но вы не дали никакой полезной информации на мой вопрос.

Comment: @dmitrij: Это да. Но ведь и вы не привели весь релевантный код.

Опубликуйте _минимальный пример_ воспроизводящий проблему. Тогда будет понятно, где неправильно. Кода, который вы дали, недостаточно для идентификации причин вылета.

Comment: pastebin.com/cL3gGepX

Comment: Действительно, после комментирования вылета нет. Может, подскажете, как же поступать в таких случаях. Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: @dmitrij, когда в `swap()` Вы поменяли `array[0]` c `array[i]` Вы тем самым для кода

 for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
  cout << '\n';
  for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
   cout << setw(2) << *(*array + i * n + j) << " ";
 }

сместили начало массива на его середину (строку i). Первая его часть  будет (для такого кода) недоступна, а вот остаток придется на память, которую Вы не выделяли.

Вот и ошибка.

-- Вообще не совсем ясно, чего же Вы хотите.


Для правильной работы придется добавить к массиву указателей на строки  еще один указатель -- на начало выделенной памяти (и модифицировать алгоритмы).

Comment: @dmitrij: Ну, чтобы работало, надо исправить код, чтобы он не обращался по неправильному указателю. Достаточно по идее просто везде вместо `*(*array + i * n + j)` использовать `array[i][j]`. (Ну и во `free_array` что-то придумать.) После этого в вашем коде не будет undefined behaviour, и остальные методы будут работать.

Вообще в случае «необъяснимых» багов стоит откомпилировать в debug-режиме, убирая все возможные оптимизации. Посмотрите, какие ключи компилятора и инструментальные средства доступны на вашей платформе.

Comment: @dmitrij: Например, для MSVC отладочный режим включается установкой DEBUG-таргета (вот [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh712wwf.aspx) документация о том, что доступно). Для связки Linux/gcc вам возможно подойдeт инструменты наподобие dmalloc или efence. Ну и конечно valgrind.

Comment: Если "в лоб", то "исправить" `free_array` довольно просто. Надо найти минимальный указатель из `array[]` и использовать в `delete []` его.

--

Вообще же, если нужен такой "двойственный подход", то можно при создании такой структуры памяти отвести под указатели на строки m+1 элемент и в `array[m]` элементе (последнем, это как бы фиктивная строка) всегда хранить **реальный адрес начала массива**.

После этого можно как угодно переставлять строки и получать доступ к переставленным элементам по `array[i][j]`, а к исходной последовательности по `array[m] + i * n + j`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь